# Wordpress get_post_meta display multiple fields as list

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I have 10 meta boxes setup. Users can upload an image to each metabox and it will display as a thumbnail on the front end. I have it working but my code needs simplifying. The problem I'm having is how to loop through each metabox ID. I'll try and explain further:

My meta boxes are set up like this:

```
'fields' => array(
        array(
                'name' => 'Image 1',
                'desc' => 'Upload an image',
                'id'   => $prefix . 'image1',
                'type' => 'file',
                'save_id' => true, // save ID using true
                'allow' => array( 'url', 'attachment' ) // limit to just attachments with array( 'attachment' )
        ),
        array(
                'name' => 'Image 2',
                'desc' => 'Upload an image',
                'id'   => $prefix . 'image2',
                'type' => 'file',
                'save_id' => true, // save ID using true
                'allow' => array( 'url', 'attachment' ) // limit to just attachments with array( 'attachment' )


            ),
        array(
                'name' => 'Image 3',
                'desc' => 'Upload an image',
                'id'   => $prefix . 'image3',
                'type' => 'file',
                'save_id' => true, // save ID using true
                'allow' => array( 'url', 'attachment' ) // limit to just attachments with array( 'attachment' )


            ),
```

I have it working using get_post_meta like this:

```
<?php $attachment_id = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'image1_id', true ); ?>
            <?php if ( ! empty( $attachment_id ) ) : ?>

               <div class="container"><div class="row">
                 <ul class="image-thumbs">

        <li class="thumbs"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'my-thumb-size' ); ?></li>
           <?php endif; ?>
           <?php $attachment_id = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'image2_id', true ); ?>
           <?php if ( ! empty( $attachment_id ) ) : ?>
           <li class="thumbs"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'my-thumb-size' ); ?></li>
           <?php endif; ?>
           <?php $attachment_id = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'image3_id', true ); ?>
           <?php if ( ! empty( $attachment_id ) ) : ?>
           <li class="thumbs"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'my-thumb-size' ); ?></li>
           <?php endif; ?>
           <?php $attachment_id = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'image4_id', true ); ?>
           <?php if ( ! empty( $attachment_id ) ) : ?>
           <li class="thumbs"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'my-thumb-size' ); ?></li>
           <?php endif; ?>
```

But I'm trying to work out how to simplify this. It seems way to much code and I'm sure there is a more efficient way of doing this. This is ay attempt at simplifying but I can only get one id at a time:

```
<!--        Look to see if there's an image uploaded and then output as a thumbnail-->
               <?php $attachment_id = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'image1_id' ); ?>

                                <?php if ( ! empty( $attachment_id ) ) : ?>
                                <div class="container">
                                 <div class="row">
                                  <ul class="image-thumbs">

                                <?php foreach( $attachment_id as $thumb ) {
                                        echo '<li class="thumbs">';
                                        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $thumb, 'my-thumb-size' );
                                        echo '</li>';

                                  } ?>

                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>                

                <?php endif; ?>
```

So my question is: how do I get multiple ids for each metabox? At the moment I can only get 1, for example "image1_id". How can I get image1_id, image2_id, image3_id etc and display as a list item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function to output all meta data for a post in a multi-dimensional array.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom

With that function you should be able to loop through your data like you want to make your code less redundant.

Here is an example function that I just wrote. I created four metaboxes attached to posts, and then used this to output them. It uses strpos to filter out just the meta fields I want.

```
function my_get_meta_data() {
global $post;

$custom_fields = get_post_custom( $post->ID );

foreach ( $custom_fields as $key => $fields ) {

    // _test_ is the $prefix for these metaboxes
    if ( strpos( $key, '_test_' ) !== false ) {
        if ( isset( $fields[0] ) ) {

            // THIS IS WHERE YOU WOULD SETUP YOUR OUTPUT
            echo $fields[0] . '<br />';
        }
    }
} // end foreach

 // Dump your metaboxes to see whats there
 // echo '<pre>';
 // var_dump($custom_fields);
 // echo '</pre>';

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did play around with get_post_custom but I couldn't figure out how to get what I needed. I'll have another go. I was thinking there would be a way to specify the ids of my image metaboxes in an array or something.

Comment: I'll have to setup something to test. I'll get back to you if I get some sample code together.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I had a play around with get_post_custom again and have the same problem: I can only specify 1 metabox at a time. I don't understand how to get multiple metaboxes.

`$custom_fields = get_post_custom( get_the_ID() ); 
 $my_custom_field = $custom_fields['image1'];`

But I want to be able to get image1, image2, image3 etc. Can I not use an array in there somehow? You'll have to excuse my poor coding knowledge, I'm trying to learn.

Comment: I added example code that I just tested for your specific setup.

Comment: Thanks that worked. At least I now have the metaboxes I want. Just need to work out how to break them up into a list now.